# Problema con formulario de login en JSF mas Hibernate

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, glassfish, mariadb

Hola tengo un problema con un formulario de login con JSF mas Hibernate,resulta que tengo la siguiente base de datos creada con MariaDB:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Versión del servidor:         10.0.21-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
-- SO del servidor:              Win64
-- HeidiSQL Versión:             9.1.0.4867
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Volcando estructura de base de datos para persistencia
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `persistencia` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `persistencia`;

-- Volcando estructura para tabla persistencia.empleado
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleado` (
  `codEmpleado` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codEmpleado`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_empleado_usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`codEmpleado`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`codUsuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- La exportación de datos fue deseleccionada.


-- Volcando estructura para tabla persistencia.usuario
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
  `codUsuario` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clave` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`codUsuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- La exportación de datos fue deseleccionada.
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Tengo la siguiente configuracion de persistencia en Hibernate:

```
<code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory >
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/persistencia?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">12345</property>      
        <mapping resource="com/afal3d/modelo/pojos/Usuario.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/afal3d/modelo/pojos/Empleado.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
</code>
```

Me genero los siguientes modelos:

```
package com.afal3d.modelo.pojos;
// Generated 14/09/2016 06:46:09 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


/**
 * Usuario generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Usuario  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private Byte codUsuario;
 private String nombre;
 private String clave;
 private Empleado empleado;

public Usuario() {
}


public Usuario(String nombre, String clave) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.clave = clave;
}
public Usuario(String nombre, String clave, Empleado empleado) {
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.clave = clave;
   this.empleado = empleado;
}

public Byte getCodUsuario() {
    return this.codUsuario;
}

public void setCodUsuario(Byte codUsuario) {
    this.codUsuario = codUsuario;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getClave() {
    return this.clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}
public Empleado getEmpleado() {
    return this.empleado;
}

public void setEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
    this.empleado = empleado;
}

}


package com.afal3d.modelo.pojos;
// Generated 14/09/2016 06:46:09 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

/**
 * Empleado generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Empleado  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private byte codEmpleado;
 private Usuario usuario;
 private String nombres;
 private String apellido;
 private char sexo;

public Empleado() {
}

public Empleado(Usuario usuario, String nombres, String apellido, char sexo) {
   this.usuario = usuario;
   this.nombres = nombres;
   this.apellido = apellido;
   this.sexo = sexo;
}

public byte getCodEmpleado() {
    return this.codEmpleado;
}

public void setCodEmpleado(byte codEmpleado) {
    this.codEmpleado = codEmpleado;
}
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return this.usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
public String getNombres() {
    return this.nombres;
}

public void setNombres(String nombres) {
    this.nombres = nombres;
}
public String getApellido() {
    return this.apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}
public char getSexo() {
    return this.sexo;
}

public void setSexo(char sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14/09/2016 06:46:11 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class catalog="persistencia" name="com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Empleado" optimistic-lock="version" table="empleado">
    <id name="codEmpleado" type="byte">
      <column name="codEmpleado"/>
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">usuario</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one class="com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Usuario" constrained="true" name="usuario"/>
    <property name="nombres" type="string">
      <column length="50" name="nombres" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="apellido" type="string">
      <column length="50" name="apellido" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="sexo" type="char">
      <column length="1" name="sexo" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14/09/2016 06:46:11 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class catalog="persistencia" name="com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Usuario" optimistic-lock="version" table="usuario">
    <id name="codUsuario" type="java.lang.Byte">
      <column name="codUsuario"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="nombre" type="string">
      <column length="50" name="nombre" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="clave" type="string">
      <column length="16" name="clave" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one class="com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Empleado" name="empleado"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Tengo las siguientes clases Dao:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.afal3d.dao;

import com.afal3d.controlador.util.NewHibernateUtil;
import com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Empleado;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;

/**
 *
 * @author AFAL3D
 */
public class EmpleadoDAO {

    private Session session;
    private Transaction trans;
    private List<Empleado> lstEmpleados;

    public void Registrar(Empleado emp) throws Exception {
        try {
            session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            trans = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(emp);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            trans.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void Eliminar(Empleado emp) throws Exception {
        try {
            session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            trans = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(emp);
            trans.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            trans.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void Modificar(Empleado emp) throws Exception {
        try {
            session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            trans = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(emp);
            trans.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            trans.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    public List<Empleado> Listar()throws Exception{
        try {
            session=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria cri=session.createCriteria(Empleado.class);
            cri.addOrder(Order.asc("apellido"));
            lstEmpleados=cri.list();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return lstEmpleados;
    }

}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.afal3d.dao;

import com.afal3d.controlador.util.NewHibernateUtil;
import com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Usuario;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

/**
 *
 * @author AFAL3D
 */
public class UsuarioDAO {

    private Session session;

    public Usuario verificarDatos(Usuario usuario) throws Exception {
        Usuario us = null;
        try {
            session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            String hql = "FROM Usuario WHERE nombre = '" + usuario.getNombre()
                    + "' and clave = '" + usuario.getClave() + "'";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

            if (!query.list().isEmpty()) {
                us = (Usuario) query.list().get(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return us;
    }
}
```

Estas son las clases beans:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.afal3d.beans;

import com.afal3d.dao.UsuarioDAO;
import com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Usuario;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author AFAL3D
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
//@RequestScoped
public class UsuarioBean {

    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String verificarDatos() throws Exception {
        UsuarioDAO usuDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
        Usuario us;
        String resultado;

        try {
            // Enviando la encriptacion
            //String encript = DigestUtils.md5Hex(this.usuario.getNombre());
            String encript = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(this.usuario.getClave());
            this.usuario.setClave(encript);

            us = usuDAO.verificarDatos(this.usuario);
            if (us != null) {

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                        .getSessionMap().put("usuario", us);

                resultado = "exito"; // recalcar que el faces-redirect=true,
                // olvida la peticion anterior y se
                // dirige a la vista
            } else {
                resultado = "error";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return resultado;
    }

    public boolean verificarSesion() {
        boolean estado;

        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().get("usuario") == null) {
            estado = false;
        } else {
            estado = true;
        }

        return estado;
    }

    public String cerrarSesion() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .invalidateSession();
        return "index";
    }
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.afal3d.beans;

import com.afal3d.dao.EmpleadoDAO;
import com.afal3d.modelo.pojos.Empleado;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author AFAL3D
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
//@RequestScoped
public class EmpleadoBean {

    private Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
    private EmpleadoDAO empleadoDAO = new EmpleadoDAO();
    private List<Empleado> lstEmpleados;

    public Empleado getEmpleado() {
        return empleado;
    }

    public void setEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        this.empleado = empleado;
    }

    public List<Empleado> getLstEmpleados() {
        return lstEmpleados;
    }

    public void setLstEmpleados(List<Empleado> lstEmpleados) {
        this.lstEmpleados = lstEmpleados;
    }

    public void registrar() throws Exception {
        empleadoDAO.Registrar(this.empleado);
    }

    public void eliminar(Empleado emp) throws Exception {
        empleadoDAO.Eliminar(emp);
        this.listar();
    }

    public String leer(Empleado emp) {
        this.empleado = emp;
        return "editar";
    }

    /*
     * Luego de cargar los datos del objeto con el metodo leer, puedo modificar
     * con nuevos datos
     */
    public String modificar() throws Exception {
        empleadoDAO.Modificar(this.empleado);
        return "exito";
    }

    public void listar() throws Exception {
        this.lstEmpleados = empleadoDAO.Listar();
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase controlador:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.afal3d.controlador.util;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author AFAL3D
 */
public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("com/afal3d/xml/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Estas las Web Pages:
INDEX.XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head></h:head>
    <body>
        <h:form>

            <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>

            <h:messages />

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">           

                <h:outputLabel value="Usuario" />
                <h:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.nombre}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Clave" />
                <h:inputSecret value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.clave}" />

                <h:commandButton value="Iniciar" action="#{usuarioBean.verificarDatos()}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EXITO.XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head></h:head>
    <body>
        <h:outputLabel value="USTED NO HA INICIADO SESIÓN" rendered="#{usuarioBean.verificarSesion() eq true}" />
        <h:form rendered="#{usuarioBean.verificarSesion()}">            
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h1>Bienvenido Usuario:</h1>

                <h:outputLabel value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.nombre}" />

                <h:commandButton value="Cerrar Sesión"
                                 action="#{usuarioBean.cerrarSesion()}" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h2>CRUD - Empleados:</h2>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Nombre" />
                <h:inputText value="#{empleadoBean.empleado.nombres}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Apellidos" />
                <h:inputText value="#{empleadoBean.empleado.apellido}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Sexo" />
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{empleadoBean.empleado.sexo}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="MASCULINO"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="FEMENINO"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>          
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{empleadoBean.listar()}" value="Listar" />
            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{empleadoBean.registrar()}" value="Registrar" />

            <h:dataTable value="#{empleadoBean.lstEmpleados}" var="emp">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Nombres" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{emp.nombres}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Apellidos" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{emp.apellido}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Sexo" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{emp.sexo}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Eliminar" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink actionListener="#{empleadoBean.eliminar(emp)}"
                                   value="Eliminar" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Modificar" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{empleadoBean.leer(emp)}"
                                   value="Modificar" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

ERROR.XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

    <h:head></h:head> 
    <body> 
        ERROR - SESSION NO INICIADA
    </body> 
</html>
```

EDITAR.XHTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>MODIFICAR EMPLEADO</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Nombres" />
                <h:inputText value="#{empleadoBean.empleado.nombres}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Apellidos" />
                <h:inputText value="#{empleadoBean.empleado.apellido}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Sexo" />
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{empleadoBean.empleado.sexo}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="MASCULINO" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="FEMENINO" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:commandButton action="#{empleadoBean.modificar()}"
                                 value="Modificar" />

                <h:commandButton action="exito" immediate="true" value="Cancelar" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Al momento de iniciar el servidor GlassFish Server  en Netbeans 8.1 y mostrarme el formulario de usuario y contraseña,los introduzco y presiono el boton de login, no los reconoce y me manda siempre a la pagina de  ERROR - SESSION NO INICIADA,no entiendo por que pasa esto ,tendrá algo que ver la encriptacion de la clave,les agradezco la ayuda que puedan brindarme para poder seguir avanzando en esta area de programación.
Adjunto link del proyecto:

[JSF_Login_Mas_Hibernate](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxueadv92q7e4i8/JSF_Login_Mas_Hibernate.zip?dl=0)

---

> An Error Occurred: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml
>   @23,91 action="#{usuarioBean.verificarDatos}": Method not found:
>   com.afal3d.beans.UsuarioBean@78a6faa0.verificarDatos()

- Stack Trace

> javax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException:
>   javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @23,91
>   action="#{usuarioBean.verificarDatos}": Method not found:
>   com.afal3d.beans.UsuarioBean@78a6faa0.verificarDatos()    at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:91)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @23,91
>   action="#{usuarioBean.verificarDatos}": Method not found:
>   com.afal3d.beans.UsuarioBean@78a6faa0.verificarDatos()    at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>     ... 36 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la especificación, EL de JSF cuando haces la llamada a un action no debe llevar los paréntesis, en el la definición del boton, 
action="#{usuarioBean.verificarDatos()}"

Sustituye esto por algo como lo siguiente:

```
    <h:commandButton value="Iniciar sesion" actionListener="#{semaforosBean.botonFijarProrroga}"/>    

<!-- este no tiene parentesis y tiene un actionListener, no solo un action --!>
```

En el lado del bean, tu método debería tener la siguiente estructura:

```
        public void botonFijarProrroga(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
/////aqui el action event, es el que nos permite cachar el evento click en el boton y comenzar a realizar la accion

        }
```

Saludos

Comment: Podrías indicarme exactamente lo que tengo que hacer para que mi código de JSF y bean funcione corrigiendo lo que ya tengo.Que deberia agregar exactamente en  public void botonFijarProrroga.

Comment: Podrías indicarme exactamente lo que tengo que hacer para que mi código de JSF y bean funcione corrigiendo lo que ya tengo.Cambio la clase verificardatos por botonFijarProrroga? o simplemente le agrego a verificardatos el ActionEvent actionEvent.

Comment: En verificarDatos añade el action event, ese botonFijarProrroga Es Algo que yo tengo en mi aplicacion asi se llama mi metodo, solo incluye el ActionEvent en tu metodo, si te sale algun error por favor pega el log, para ver que pasa

Comment: Podrías mostrarme como lo hiciste vos,haciendo lo que me dices no anda aun.

Comment: Ok, pues lo que dice el stackTrace es que no encuentra el metodo, prueba realizando esto:

Asigna un nombre a tu ManagedBean 
@ManagedBean(name="usuarioBean")

Y llámalo por medio de ese nombre en tu commandButton

<p:commandButton value="Iniciar sesión" actionListener="#{loginBean.validarUsuario}" ajax="true" update=":form" />

Comment: Esto ya no es cierto desde JSF 2.0

Comment: Ok gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, pues lo que dice el stackTrace es que no encuentra el metodo, prueba realizando esto:

Asigna un nombre a tu ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="usuarioBean")
@SessionScoped
public class usuarioBean implements Serializable{
   private String usuario;
   private String contrasenia;

   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{UsuarioServicio}")
   private UsuarioService usuarioService;

   public void verificarDatos(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
       Usuario u=usuarioService.validarUsuario(usuario, getContrasenia());
       if(u!=null){
           FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
           HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
           session.setAttribute("login", true);
           session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300);
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/EngineTest/main.xhtml");

       }else{

           FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Usuario no valido");
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
       }

   }

    /**
     * @return the usuario
     */
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param usuario the usuario to set
     */
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }


    /**
     * @return the usuarioService
     */
    public UsuarioService getUsuarioService() {
        return usuarioService;
    }

    /**
     * @param usuarioService the usuarioService to set
     */
    public void setUsuarioService(UsuarioService usuarioService) {
        this.usuarioService = usuarioService;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contrasenia
     */
    public String getContrasenia() {
        return contrasenia;
    }

    /**
     * @param contrasenia the contrasenia to set
     */
    public void setContrasenia(String contrasenia) {
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }

}
```

Y llámalo por medio de ese nombre en tu commandButton

```
<p:commandButton value="Iniciar sesión" actionListener="#{loginBean.verificarDatos}" ajax="true" update=":form" />
```

Utilizo `<p:commandButton>` en lugar de `<h:commandButton>` porque estoy utilizando primefaces.